# Programatically Launch desktop App-2 from desktop app-1 in separate JVM

Tags: java, jar, desktop-application

I have two Java Desktop Applications App-1 & App-2. App-2 is programatically launched by App-1 when it starts, using this line of code.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java","-jar","App-2.jar", ""});
```

But App-2 launches an embedded database.

I'm having issues when launching App-2 from inside of App-1 like stated above but everything works fine when these two desktop apps are launched individually.
Is there anything I can do to launch the two applications in separate JVMs ?

Comment: Please specify what issues you have when launching "from inside App-1". Does it launch at all, or does it fail because you have not specified the full path to `java`?

Comment: db locking issues probably due to emebedded database running in same jvm ..

Comment: You *are* using separate JVMs in the above code. Check the running processes

Comment: Side note: are you sure you want to launch APP2 from within APP1? Consider a different option: have one application that "manages" which apps should be running? I guess your solution works on a small scale, but as soon as you are talking about several components/apps, I would rather avoid such tight coupling as you have there.

Comment: Sometimes app-2 gets stuck somewhere if app-1 is still running & as soon as app-1 is terminated then app-2 starts working absolutely fine.